# Flex mobile: Can I "add to contacts" some info like name, email, phone?

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, flex-mobile

Basically create a new contact in the Contacts on iOS and whatever is equivalent on Android.

Comment: You'll have to use (or create) a Native Extension to access the contact APIs in the underlying mobile OS.  This is not built natively into Adobe AIR.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [ContactEditor](https://github.com/memeller/ContactEditor) Native Extension, available on Github. It's a native extension for Adobe Air Mobile which works with both iOS and Android. It allows you to add new contacts to your native contact list from an air app. ContactEditor is written by [Paweł Meller](https://github.com/memeller) and [Mateusz Maćkowiak](https://github.com/mateuszmackowiak).